# linked files not working when uploaded to web server

Tags: html, css, linux, apache

I've been working on this website for my school, and when i work in local (atom/wamp/etc..) everything works fine, but when i upload the files to my web server (old laptop i put ubuntu 18.04 and installed lamp server), css files, images and href links are not working.
I understand this is a problem in files path that works in local but not when uploaded to a linux server because of the "../" directing to root or something.

that's the index.php how it looks on local
[image]

And that's what it looks on the webserver 
[image]

That's how are my files organized (generated with tree windows cmd)

```
C:.
|   index.php
|   README.md
|   tree.txt       
+---css
|       accueil.css
|       footer.css
|       header.css
|       
+---fonts
|       Lato-Black.ttf
|       Lato-BlackItalic.ttf
|       Lato-Bold.ttf
|       Lato-BoldItalic.ttf
|       Lato-Hairline.ttf
|       Lato-HairlineItalic.ttf
|       Lato-Heavy.ttf
|       Lato-HeavyItalic.ttf
|       Lato-Italic.ttf
|       Lato-Light.ttf
|       Lato-LightItalic.ttf
|       Lato-Medium.ttf
|       Lato-MediumItalic.ttf
|       Lato-Regular.ttf
|       Lato-Semibold.ttf
|       Lato-SemiboldItalic.ttf
|       Lato-Thin.ttf
|       Lato-ThinItalic.ttf
|       Oswald-Bold.ttf
|       Oswald-BoldItalic.ttf
|       Oswald-Demi-BoldItalic.ttf
|       Oswald-DemiBold.ttf
|       Oswald-Extra-LightItalic.ttf
|       Oswald-ExtraLight.ttf
|       Oswald-Heavy.ttf
|       Oswald-HeavyItalic.ttf
|       Oswald-Light.ttf
|       Oswald-LightItalic.ttf
|       Oswald-Medium.ttf
|       Oswald-MediumItalic.ttf
|       Oswald-RegularItalic.ttf
|       Oswald-Stencil.ttf
|       oswald.regular.ttf
|       PlayfairDisplay-Black.otf
|       PlayfairDisplay-BlackItalic.otf
|       PlayfairDisplay-Bold.otf
|       PlayfairDisplay-BoldItalic.otf
|       PlayfairDisplay-Italic.otf
|       PlayfairDisplay-Regular.otf
|       PlayfairDisplaySC-Black.otf
|       PlayfairDisplaySC-BlackItalic.otf
|       PlayfairDisplaySC-Bold.otf
|       PlayfairDisplaySC-BoldItalic.otf
|       PlayfairDisplaySC-Italic.otf
|       PlayfairDisplaySC-Regular.otf
|       
+---images
|   |   cedex.png
|   |   fax.png
|   |   Fb.png
|   |   horaire.png
|   |   identite_photo.jpg
|   |   instagram.png
|   |   localisation.png
|   |   Logo.png
|   |   logo_header.png
|   |   mail.png
|   |   notre_histoire_photo.jpg
|   |   Partenaire1.jpg
|   |   Partenaire2.png
|   |   Partenaire3.png
|   |   Partenaire4.jpg
|   |   paysage.jpg
|   |   region.png
|   |   site.png
|   |   slide1.jpg
|   |   slide2.jpg
|   |   slide3.jpg
|   |   tel.png
|   |   twitter.png
|   |   valeurs_photo.jpg
|   |   
|   \---favicon
|           android-chrome-192x192.png
|           android-chrome-512x512.png
|           favicon-16x16.png
|           favicon-32x32.png
|           favicon.ico
|           
+---includes
|       accueil.html
|       footer.html
|       header.html
|       slide.js
|       
\---pages
    +---accueil
    +---activite
    |       activite.css
    |       activite.php
    |       
    +---adhesion
    |       adhesion.php
    |       
    +---connaitre_la_cftc
    |       connaitre_la_cftc.css
    |       connaitre_la_cftc.php
    |       histoire.css
    |       histoire.php
    |       identite.css
    |       identite.php
    |       valeurs_et_identite.css
    |       valeurs_et_identite.php
    |       
    +---coordonnees
    |       coordonnees.css
    |       coordonnees.php
    |       federation_cftc_fpt.css
    |       federation_cftc_fpt.php
    |       syndicat_cftc_fpt_34.css
    |       syndicat_cftc_fpt_34.php
    |       ud34.css
    |       ud34.php
    |       
    +---syndicat_la_cftc
    |       syndicat_la_cftc.css
    |       syndicat_la_cftc.php
    |       
    +---templates
    |       template_header_footer.php
    |       
    +---viepratique
    |       viepratique.php
    |       
    \---viepro
            formation.css
            formation.php
            viepro.css
            viepro.php
```

And here's some samples of my files :

index.php (in main directory of my site)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../IMAGES\favicon\favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../IMAGES/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <title>Accueil CFTC</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php include ('includes/header.html'); ?>
    <?php include ('includes/accueil.html'); ?>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 </body>
   <?php include ('includes/footer.html'); ?>
</html>
```

my header file (in /includes/header.html) , (linked css is in /css/header.css).

Not going to put all the code because it just repeats itself

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/header.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../../IMAGES\favicon\favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../../IMAGES/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
  <title>Header</title>
</head>


<body>
  <header>
  <div id="header_bar">
    <div id="header_bar_text" class="gpd-text">Syndicat Constructif, Partenaire du Dialogue Social
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div href="/index.php" id="logo_header"><img src="/images/logo_header.png"></div>
    <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop"/>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a target="_blank" href="/index.php">Accueil</a></li>
      <li>
        <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Connaitre la CFTC +</label>
        <a target="_blank" href="/pages/connaitre_la_cftc/connaitre_la_cftc.php">Connaitre la CFTC</a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
        <ul>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="/pages/connaitre_la_cftc/histoire.php">Histoire</a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="/pages/connaitre_la_cftc/valeurs_et_identite.php">Valeurs et Identité</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

And one example of pages i've got on the site (only putting one example because they are all the same "layout")
(all pages has theire .css files in the same folder except header and footer and "accueil").

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../../IMAGES\favicon\favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../../IMAGES/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="connaitre_la_cftc.css">
    <title>Connaitre la CFTC</title>
  </head>

  <!-- HEADER DE LA PAGE -->
   <?php include ('../../includes/header.html'); ?>

  <body>
    <br>
    <div id="i16x">
      <a href="histoire.php" class="gpd-button1" id="i6rl">Histoire</a>
      <a href="valeurs_et_identite.php" class="gpd-button1" id="ik2f">Valeurs et identité</a>
    </div>
    <br>
 </body>

  <!-- FOOTER DE LA PAGE -->
  <?php include ('../../includes/footer.html'); ?>
</html>
```

Just wanted to say also , not only css files are not linked , images and fonts also.
Thanks for reading and i'll take any kind of help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things.. `"../../IMAGES\favicon\favicon-32x32.png"` is probably not going to fly on a web server. If xxx.com is your site, and your images are in (webroot)/images/, then just link to

`/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png`

Same with css.. Just make sure the directories line up.
In your example you are attempting to link to the webroot directory with

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="connaitre_la_cftc.css">`

However, you said your css files are in the css folder? So perhaps try

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/connaitre_la_cftc.css">`

instead?

Honestly this is hard to help without seeing the page live but if you are in doubt that something is loading just inspect source and try to go to the file directly (right click, press inspect source, and click on the href to see if it loads, and where it is trying to load from). You can then move things around on your server until it works.

Comment: thanks , my .css files are in the same folder for each pages like for pages/page1/page.html and page.css

Comment: Hmm okay that should work then.. For the page you screenshoted that isn't loading the css correctly, what happens when you try to go to the css document directly? Does it load? If not, what is the url it tries to go to?

Comment: Actually the solution was even easier than that, i've read your answer again and used the tip you gave me with the inspect element, css files were linked to www directory , i only added the /site_name/ infront of everything and it worked.. Thanks dude !